# Delayed opening of first php file

Tags: php, aptana

After I first start Aptana and the first php file I open it takes about 2 or more minutes for Aptana to open the file.  It just sits there with the loading spinning away.  This has been happening for about 3 weeks or more.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?  This was so annoying that I start upgrading Aptana with the nightly builds hoping that it would get fixed but no such luck.  Any php file opened after the very first php file opens just fine, it is just the very first php file and only with php files.

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to load something from a network drive or other remote resource that's not responding, and then caches that lack of availability for the rest of the session.

Comment: @Quasdunk: Questions about programmer tools are **on-topic** here. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Robert Harvey sorry, my bad! Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to file a bug on this at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Please include relevant details such as the contents of your log file (Help > Studio > View log file), Studio version #, the PHP file (if a particular one, rather than just any file triggers this), and details on if there's jobs/threads being run that are causing it to be slow (Open the Progress view, Window > Show View > Progress, leave it open and then restart and open the PHP file).

Also if this just started happening as a result of upgrading from one particular version to another, that would be helpful.